# Would like to use System.Zip.TZipFile in Delphi XE7 but can not find it in the Tool Palette

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

We are currently using ZipTV for file compression. We are trying to eliminate third party components for easy upgrades to newer Delphi versions. We came across System.Zip.TZipFile but can not find it in the XE7 Delphi Tool Palette. Does anyone know how we can add this to our application. Here is a link to the Embarcadero Documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Zip.TZipFile

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 8):

`TZipFile` isn't a component that you access from the Tool Palette. In the same way as you do with, for example `TFileStream`, you create an instance of this class in code, without using a design surface.

```
uses
  System.Zip;
.... 
var
  ZipFile: TZipFile;
.... 
ZipFile := TZipFile.Create;
try
  // use the object
finally
  ZipFile.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Remy and David.